# Facebook Graph API - events request by pixel_id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to integrate facebook graph api server-to-server to track events page view and registration

My company invited my business facebook and my access is
Partial access
Basic, Apps and integrations

but when I go to Apps section to create the app, it's showing only business admin can take this action,.

Do I need admin access or can I integrate FB graph pixel API with basic access?

I go to Apps section to create the app, it's showing only business admin can take this action,.

Do I need admin access or can I integrate FB graph pixel API with basic access?